# How to find group by group name

Tags: liferay

How to find `com.liferay.portal.model.Group` object by group name? Also how to find `com.liferay.portal.model.Role` by role name?

=============EDIT===============

I have `testGroup`:
[image]

```
Group group = GroupServiceUtil.getGroup(themeDisplay.getCompanyId(), "testGroup");
```

results:

```
11:09:09,858 ERROR [RuntimePageImpl-15][render_portlet_jsp:132] null
com.liferay.portal.NoSuchGroupException: No Group exists with the key {companyId=10157, name=testGroup}
    at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.GroupPersistenceImpl.findByC_N(GroupPersistenceImpl.java:3253)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.GroupLocalServiceImpl.loadGetGroup(GroupLocalServiceImpl.java:2054)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:115)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:51)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:175)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.GroupLocalServiceImpl.getGroup(GroupLocalServiceImpl.java:1196)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:115)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:175)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.GroupServiceImpl.getGroup(GroupServiceImpl.java:329)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:115)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:51)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:175)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find group and role by its name using below API methods:

```
  GroupLocalServiceUtil.getGroup(long companyId, java.lang.String name)

  RoleLocalServiceUtil.getRole(long companyId, java.lang.String name)
```

Comment: I had tried it before I asked my question and It does not work for me. I edited my question to show Excpetion which is thrown.

Comment: `GroupServiceUtil.getGroup` checks for permissions before returning group so please use `GroupLocalServiceUtil.getGroup` . One more thing, you are looking for `Group` and here in snapshot it is `UserGroup` :) . For UserGroup there is method `UserGroupLocalServiceUtil.getUserGroup(companyId,name)`